# Closure Definition Intuition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space. Consider a subset $E$ of $S$, then the closure is the intersection of all closed sets contained in $E$. I am trying to understand the intuition behind this definition for the closure of the set $E$. Do we define the closure this way so that we have a unique closure of a set?

Comment: The closure will be the smallest closed set that contains $E$. The intersection of an arbitrary amount of closed sets will be closed. Thus, the intersection of all closed sets that contain $E$ will be a closed set that contains $E$ and every other closed set that contains $E$ will contain the intersection. So it is **the** smallest closed set containing $E$.

Comment: Yea I sort of figured that. Thanks, I just wanted clarification.

Comment: Captain. Nice explanation.

Comment: This definition also easily shows that the closure is closed (and the closure operator is idempotent, cl(cl(A))=cl(A)  ).